# SQL query scenario.

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Suppose I have the following table:

[image]

My goal is to display a select resultset that looks like this:

[image]

The tricky part here is to display the AverageCostPerType column for every single book.

I know how to get the AverageCostPerType, it's simply the following: 
SELECT avg(bookcost) as AverageCostPerType FROM BOOK GROUPBY BookType;

This will display 3 rows since I have 3 distinct types. How can I display an averagecostpertype for each book ?

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried to find a solution yet? If so, show us what you have tried. Right now you're asking us to design a solution for you, which someone may actually do if you're lucky, but it's not really what SO is here for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the average per booktype in a derived table and `join` it to the original table to get the result.

```
select book_num, t.booktype, x.avgcost, bookcost, x.avgcost-bookcost
from tablename t join 
(select booktype, avg(bookcost) as avgcost from tablename group by booktype) x
on t.booktype = x.booktype
```

Answer (score 4):

you need use [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm)

AVG per BookType

```
select b.*, avg(bookcost) over (PARTITION BY BookType)
from book b
```

AVG for all books

```
select b.*, avg(bookcost) over ()
from book b
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [aggregate](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) functions with an analytic partition window to get average cost by booktype.

This allows you to perform the query without joining the table to itself, or using nested select statements.

[Oracle Aggregate Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035)

```
select Book_num,
    BookType,
    avg(BookCost) over(partition by BookType) as AverageCostPerType,
    BookCost,
    BookCost - avg(BookCost) over(partition by BookType) as Difference
from YourBookTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.*, 
       b2.AverageCostPerType, 
       b2.AverageCostPerType - b.BookCost as difference
from book b
join 
(
  SELECT BookType, avg(bookcost) as AverageCostPerType 
  FROM BOOK 
  GROUP BY BookType
) b2 on b.BookType = b2.BookType
```

Comment: You should change to `b.BookCost -  b2.AverageCostPerType`